# Count at the end of a month in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, level-of-detail

I want to find the number of customers per subscription plan at the end of the acquisition month.

As you can see in [the workbook](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000ON207SAD/count-at-the-end-of-a-month), customers can change their subscription plan on any date, but I only want to find the subscription plan at the end of the acquisition month.

I created a field, called **EOM Acquisition**, but need to find the desired output below for any given month of acquisition. (in sample dataset only October).

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: If that helped, please also upvote as normally desired on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please proceed like this.  Create a new calculated field say `calculation1` as follows-

```
IF [Date] = [EOM Acquisition] then [Subscription Plan] END
```

drag this field instead of `subs plan` in view and filter out `null` values, you'll get what you want

[image]

**Another way** add a calc field as follows

```
IF [Date] = [EOM Acquisition] then 1 ELSE 0 END
```

And thereafter add sum on this field as measure alongwith EOM and subscription fields.

[image]